# Can I embed a custom font in an Android application?

Tags: android, fonts

I would like to have an app include a custom font for rendering text, load it, and then use it with standard elements like StaticText. Is this possible?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Yes you can, you jsut can't define it into xml layouts. You need to use it dynamically each time. Check [this tutorial](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/) for instance.

In case link is dead, here is a sum up of the stuff :

- Get a font file like `times.otf`
- Drop it in your asset folder, inside a "fonts" folder
- Get a reference of TextView with something like that:

  ```
  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myCustomTVFont);
  ```
- Grab you font from the asset folder:

  ```
  Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/times.otf");
  ```
- Make your TextView look great:

  ```
  tv.setTypeface(tf);
  ```

Comment: Hope the tutorial won't disappear one day.

Comment: As Martin rightly pointed it out, this needs a little edit, in case the link died out.

Comment: This tutorial did helped me. This is an ultimate solution to my problem :)

Comment: Tried it on a API 2.1 device. Didn't work good. I guess maybe my font was big and caused memory issues. Or similar. I just found something that may be a fix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5941665/129202

Comment: Nice one! Worked a treat.

Comment: is android support .eot, .svg and .woff font types ?

Comment: Yeah, tutorial link is dead. Good thing you summarised it!

Comment: A copy of the original tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20140115015420/http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts

Answer (score 3):

As of Android 8.0 (API level 26), you can use fonts in XML. See the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your can take look in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787690/adding-custom-font-to-theme-in-android) as well to set custom fonts for all the views in your activity.

Comment: As in the other answer to this question, it would be really handy if the important content of the thread was inside the question, in case the link dies one day.