# reading arabic char in android

Tags: android, arabic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display unicode characters in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129098/display-unicode-characters-in-android)

hi,
How Can I read an arabic caracter on android. I have a webview in my application. But when I open a link contain arabic, arabic letters appear as tiles. Can I add an instruction or to install an application to support this caracter?

[image]

Comment: look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7962813/779408). Its solution can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some fonts. Try this: http://www.android-devs.com/?p=119

Comment: I try this but arabic letters still appear as tiles.