# Create Sqlite database with 8000 records

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'am developing an application which uses sqlite for autocomplete textview. The database has more than 8000 records. Creating a database can be done with a query in `onCreate()`. But how do i create a database with 8000+ records in it. writing insert query for 8000 records sounds worst to me.

What's the best way to create a database with 8000+ records in it. Is there any way like dumping sql file like how we do in mysql.

Comment: Have you tried the naive solution to just do the INSERT queries (in one single transaction, of course)? What was the result?

Comment: @EmilVikström No i didn't try that. I thought its a bad idea to do.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? For performance reasons or otherwise? If it's for performance reasons, how can you make such a claim without even trying?

Comment: @EmilVikström its only possible for Sqlite version 3.7.11 and above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you should put your database with a table (having 8000 records) inside the Assets folder and write a logic to **Copy existing database** inside your android app.

Check links:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6541043/379693
2. [Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Comment: The same logic is followed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 1):

What ever approach you conduct but do it in an ***SQLite Transaction*** because it will maintain a single *Journal* (*db cache*) file for inserting all the records in one go. It will really speed up things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the .sql file you may import it in phpMyadmin....
Just go to PHPMyadmin URL... 
create an empty database.... 
click on import...
Browse the sql file
click on Go...

That's it

Comment: oh really?? Do you think this is a relevant answer?