# How to import pre-made db to sqlite managed by ormlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, import, ormlite

I have a .db file and I want to setup it at first run of my android application.
I use OrmLite to manage my database.

In that .db file a have about 7000 records and when I want to import it by common methods (use foreach - create command ) it takes many time (about 2-3 mins) to import.

How can i solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: Do you use one single transaction to do all the inserts already?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let say you have database named "`prepared.db`" and your package name is "`com.example.android`". This is what I do.

1. make sure you prepared database is under assets folder.
2. In the constructor of class that extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper, check
   whether or not database exist.
3. If database **DID NOT exist**, copy db from assets folder

(Both Step 2 and 3 happen inside constructor)

This is code sample and It work for me.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "prepared.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.android/databases/";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (!dbexist) {

            // If database did not exist, try copying existing database from assets folder.
            try {
                File dir = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
                dir.mkdirs();
                InputStream myinput = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
                String outfilename = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "DB Path : " + outfilename);
                OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                myoutput.flush();
                myoutput.close();
                myinput.close();            
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    * Check whether or not database exist
    */
    private boolean checkdatabase() {
        boolean checkdb = false;

        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();

        Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "DB Exist : " + checkdb);

        return checkdb;
    }
}
```

P.S : If the database file size is more than 1mb, error will occur. You can [split database to solve](http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/10/copying-larger-database-files-in.html) such issue.

Comment: Error doesn't occur with Android greater than 2.3.3 , source:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789177/i-get-this-error-data-exceeds-uncompress-data-max-on-android-2-2-but-not-on-2-3

Comment: Also, don't forget to add: File dir = new File(DATABASE_PATH); dir.mkdirs(); before creating a new FileOutputStream. Otherwise you can get ENOENT (No such file or directory) error.

Comment: does the onCreate() and onUpgrade methods just the same as in other tutorials and official documentation or is there are any special change when using a pre-made DB?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide the data as an external db, you can dump on or more tables (definition and data) using

```
sqlite3 prepared.db ".dump mytable" > dump.sql
```

and import them using

```
sqlite3 main.db < dump.sql
```

If you want to setup things programmatically in Java, make sure that you do everything in one single transaction using [TransactionManager.callInTransaction](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#Transactions), since multiple commits (autocommits) are quite expensive in SQLite.