# Change font in all app or at least in Tab

Tags: android, fonts, tabs

Ok my first question is:
Is there a way to change the font on everything in my app? I mean to put for ex the font x.ttf to be the default font for all the buttons,listviews,for everything that is in my app? And if yes,how?

And my second question:
If that is not possible,then please tell me how to change the font on the Tab widget...

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424165/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-android-application

Comment: not duplicate,I don't wanna set the font for each widget I use,and there isn't an anaswer about changing the font in a tab

Answer (score 0):

Still There is no way to change the font for a complete application. All You can do is for Text Views create custom Text View and override the font method. Then you can use the customized text view rather than using the default text view.

This is the way I used the font Helvetica for My app.