# Custom Fonts and Custom Textview on Android

Tags: android, custom-controls, textview, typeface

From an application I need to develop, I've received a specific font that has many files like FontName-Regular, **FontName-Bold**, *FontName-it*. I need to use it in all the textviews in the application. First I thought it was an easy task. Look over SO and found a very nice thread:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926263/add-custom-font-for-complete-android-application)

So first I did like:

```
public static void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView)v).setTypeface(FONT_REGULAR);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // ignore
    }
}
```

And called this method during onCreate in my activity. Every textView in my app was showing that font and boy, was I happy for getting away so easy. Until I got to a screen where some textviews required **Bold** as `Style` (`android:textStyle="bold"`). Then I realized that this solution does not provide me with possibility to load the **Font-Bold**.ttf from assets.

Than looked further and saw a nice custom TextView implementation, in the same SO question:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/chiller.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf ,1);

    }
    }
```

This looks even better. My question is: how can I detect on  `init()` if my control has Style set to Bold or not so I can assign the requested TypeFace ?

Thank you for your time.

LE. Following the example below, I've updated my class as:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    Typeface normalTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), Constants.FONT_REGULAR);
    Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),  Constants.FONT_BOLD);

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
        if (style == Typeface.BOLD) {
            super.setTypeface(boldTypeface/*, -1*/);
        } else {
            super.setTypeface(normalTypeface/*, -1*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Well If I debug, the app goes in setTypeFace and it seems to apply the bold one, but on my layout I can't see any change, not bold. No matter what font I use, no changes are done in my TextView and is displayed with the default android font.  I wonder why ?

I have summed everything on a blog post [here on my blog](http://alinberce.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/using-custom-fonts-in-android-bold-italic-regular-you-name-it/) maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed question and elaboration, and the great blog post! Worked perfectly for me. I also subclassed Button for the same result. My only query is w.r.t. the efficiency of calling createFromAsset() _every_ time. Would it be better to load the fonts once and store them in your Application class, and access these from MyTextView.setTypeface()?

Comment: Thanks for your words. I thought about that too but didn't test to see how or if it works. It should work fine. Anyway I haven't seen any penalty of performance with many views on a screen.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The constructor of `TextView` calls `setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style)` with the `style` parameter retrieved from the XML attribute `android:textStyle`. So, if you want to intercept this call to force your own typeface you can override this method as follow:

```
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
    Typeface normalTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/your_normal_font.ttf");
    Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/your_bold_font.ttf");

    if (style == Typeface.BOLD) {
        super.setTypeface(boldTypeface/*, -1*/);
    } else {
        super.setTypeface(normalTypeface/*, -1*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alin: The problem was that `setTypeface()` is called by constructors before `Typeface`s were created! So, move the creation of `Typeface`s inside `setTypeface()` and now it will work!

Comment: I tried to use the same solution but somehow it is the setType(Typeface tf) instead of the setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) gets called, and it gets called twice. I had to make some changes to make sure the bold and italic styles are kept. Anyway this gave me the right direction and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can use my `CustomTextView` which allows you to specify a font file name in your `assets` folder:

https://github.com/mafshin/CustomTextView

and the usage is really simple:

```
<com.my.app.CustomTextView
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.app"            
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test text"
        android:id="@+id/testcustomview" 

        custom:fontAssetName="Politica XT.otf"
        />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to create your own package for custom fonts and import them in your project so that you can use them later in future

```
  package com.codeslips.utilities;  

  import android.content.Context; 
  import android.graphics.Typeface;
  import android.util.AttributeSet;
  import android.widget.TextView;  

  public class CustomTextView extends TextView {  

          public CustomTextView(Context context)
               { super(context); setFont(); }  

          public CustomTextView(Context context,AttributeSet set)
             { super(context,set); setFont(); } 

          public CustomTextView(Context context,AttributeSet set,int defaultStyle) 
             { super(context,set,defaultStyle); setFont(); } 

          private void setFont() { 

           Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/your-font.ttf"); 
           setTypeface(typeface); //function used to set font

             }  
          }
```

Now use the above class in your XML file to have your custom font

```
    <com.codeslips.utilities.CustomTextView   
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="Upload Image" 
       android:paddingTop="10sp"
       android:textSize="14sp"
       android:layout_weight="0.7"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```