# Extending TextView, can not get font type anymore

Tags: android, textview, textstyle

I created a CustomTextView that extends TextView, in the CustomTextView's constructor it has the following code:

```
Typeface tf = this.getTypeface();
boolean isBold = false;
boolean isItalic = false;
if(tf != null) {
    isBold = tf.isBold();
    isItalic = tf.isItalic();
}
```

Here the isItalic and isBold are always false. Even after I defined android:textStyle="italic" in the layout file. What could be the problem?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954484/custom-fonts-and-custom-textview-on-android)

Comment: Thank you, I got slightly different results but it is the right lead. I added comments in that thread detailing the situation I ran into.