# Custom typeface error

Tags: android

I want to change the app typeface and I can't:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
        >
...
```

style.xml

```
....

    <style name="CustomTheme">
        <item name="android:typeface">stheiti.ttf</item>
    </style>
....
```

But I get an error:

> error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'android:typeface' with
>   value 'stheiti.ttf').

But I have a rootAPP/assets/stheiti.ttf

I do not understand why get that error, I searched in many sites the solution but i couldn't found any with same problem

Thanks in advance! :=)

Comment: The unique solution who I found are the solutions of here. There isn't no way of apply whole for app :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set **custom font** in **text view** like

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "stheiti.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

If you want to implement custom font in whole application then you can **create your custom view** and set your font at the initialize of that view.

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public void init() {

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "stheiti.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf ,1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, you have to set custom font to every view by programatically (Even you can't set custom typeface through XML, yes you can set but only built-in typefaces)

Check this: [Adding custom Font to Theme in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787690/adding-custom-font-to-theme-in-android) and [Using a custom typeface in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code for that, it may help you.

```
// Font path
String fontPath = "fonts/trbuc.ttf";

// text view label
TextView txtGhost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTxtViewCustomFont);

// Loading Font Face
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), fontPath);

// Applying font
txtGhost.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

For whole application u need to make custome TextView  u can us as shown below for each and every textview of xml before going to this first make folder with naming **fonts** in asset in that fonts folder add ur font stheiti.ttf

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MyTextView extends TextView{

 public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();

    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();

    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();

    }



    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/stheiti.ttf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }


 }
```

after that for each and every textview in xml on which u want this type of font than ur textview in xml should be like this add other property of textview which u needed same as for normal textview

```
<YourProjectPackageName.MyTextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22px"
    android:textColor="#34A4c5"
 ></YourProjectPackageName>
```

and in your activity use as shown below for custome textview

```
MyTextView textview=(MyTextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
```