# How to force default font to the app? Like Gmail app doing it?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I want to force Android's default font (Roboto in ICS and something else in older ones) to all the TextViews in my android app.

It should not change when user changes it from the System preferences.

Is that even possible?

I tried to set the typeface to normal in the application's theme. But that did not work. But when I tried monospace it worked.

I do not want to include any font files in my package. I've seen GMail app doing it in ICS. How are they doing it?

Comment: I have found that there are some inconsistencies across different devices when dealing with fonts. My guess is that if you wish to make this work accross all devices you are going to have to include copies of the font files inside your package (in assets)

Answer (score 2):

Yoy can extend TextView Object, and override constructor to force font type:

```
    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf"); 
    this.setTypeface(type);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by @Stefano Ortisi is absolutely wrong. The only way you can have CUSTOM FONTS in your application is by placing it in the assets directory and access it from there:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/CUSTOMFONT.tff");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXTVIEW_ID);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Following are the links to justify my claim:

[Using a custom typeface in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android)

There was a similar post related to this issue. Check this link before even trying for the solution given in the above post:

[Custom typeface error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224688/custom-typeface-error)

Comment: You are missing a fundamental setTypeFace call in your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the theme in your application.
You can set it from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/YourCustomTheme">
```

Then you have to create your custom theme in the style.xml file where

```
<style name="YourCustomTheme" >
     <item name="android:typeface">yourcustomfont</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @Stefano Ortisi have you ever implemented the solution you have provided?

Comment: @ArunGeorge sure. You can check this little example project: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6102128/FontTest.zip

Comment: Checked the project and as I said CUSTOM FONT can only be used programmatically. The font you used in the project's `style.xml`  `serif` is one of the built-in typefaces. So you are not using a custom font but just an android build-in typeface.

So you are absolutely wrong when you say `<item name="android:typeface">yourcustomfont</item>` which could infact be  `<item name="android:typeface">AndroidBuildInFonts</item>`

Comment: I want to force the default font. I do not want to include the ttf file. By default font, I mean the one which is already installed on the device.