# How to add different font styles to device default font style list in android programmatically?

Tags: android, fonts, truetype, android-fonts

Some devices like (Samsung,htc,LG...) having an option to change device font style and download the new fonts.
 So I am planning to develop an application that contains different font styles. when user download the application, my font styles are added system font style list, then user can select the font style from the list.

I am using following code to select the font style from the list"

```
 settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS), 0);
        }
    });
```

But my problem was how to show my custom font styles along with the system font list when user click font styles in settings.

Please give me an idea how can i do that?

Comment: Did that [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787690/adding-custom-font-to-theme-in-android) not help you?

Comment: I am trying to change the device font style not for individual application.