# Android default typeface will change according to device

Tags: android

I am developing custom views for android, in my custom view i would like to use some third party typeface. But now i get confused that device default font (if differs from android version to version) may be override if i set custom font by default? or else could you tell me your opinion or advantages of using default typeface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a bit of unpredictability concerning which font will be used to render your text. On Ice Cream Sandwich and above, the default text should be rendered with Roboto. Most devices older than this will render the same text with Droid Sans. Unfortunately, there are many exceptions. [Samsung](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/tips-to-customize-samsung-galaxy-s5/) and [LG](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/09/lgs-g2-smartphone-gets-caught-living-in-the-shadows-of-giants/2/) like to allow the user to change the default typeface, which carries through to your app. Many [Amazon Fire devices apply *different* default typefaces](https://plus.google.com/+JeffGilfelt/posts/KG14smZrTgt) to *different* elements of your app. There's also the fact that [Android L will introduce a new version of Roboto](http://phandroid.com/2014/06/30/google-design-shows-off-differences-in-new-roboto-font/), although this change may not affect appearance enough to warrant concern.

What about user choice? Why does any of this matter? Well, the problem is that inconsistent fonts *will* affect your layouts. If you set things like TextViews and Buttons to be sized according to their contents, their sizes will change according to whatever font is being used at the time. Depending on your layouts, this will cause other elements to be shifted around or even partially covered up. If you set the aforementioned UI widgets to be a fixed size, you risk text being cut off or wrapped, which is also ugly.

There's no way to set a custom font by default, unfortunately. If you wish to use a custom typeface, there are a couple of strategies to follow. The first step is to bundle a font with your app. Roboto is a good choice because it is what the user is used to looking at. [You can use some utility class to apply your custom font to widgets that contain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787690/adding-custom-font-to-theme-in-android). [You could also subclass the same widgets and apply the font in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631326/use-roboto-font-in-app-with-minimum-api-level-14).

Remember how I said that there's no way to set a custom default font? Well there *kinda* is, but [it involves reflection](https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/7749076). This is not an official API and it could break at *any* point in the future (handle those exceptions!). It is actually my personal favorite solution because all the others are so messy.