# How to change Font of Whole app

Tags: android, fonts

I want to change the font of whole app.
I am referring answer given by **weston** in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application)

But this works for some devices and for some devices it doesn't work

Can anyone help me with this. Any help would be greatly Appreciated.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the app text style in your custom style file, for more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app/16407123#16407123) answer..

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787690/adding-custom-font-to-theme-in-android) question too...

Answer (score 1):

Please Look At Following questions, your answer is already there I guess

1. [Answer One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application)
2. [Answer Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app)

Please make shure there is no duplicate questions before you ask a question

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't provide such method. So you can't change font of complete app at once. 
Probably you should not change font of whole application as android's Roboto font is better looking. 
The method you referred uses reflection means it will fail on customized android like htc/nokia etc.