# Xamarin: how to add custom font to TabText or all TextView?

Tags: android, xamarin

How to Add custom font to xamarin android?

I add :
Assets/fonts/Geogrotesque Medium Italic.otf
create attrs.xml

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="TextView" >
    <attr name="fontFamily" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

create fonts.xml

```
 <familyset>
  <family>
    <nameset>
      <name>Geogrotesque</name>
    </nameset>
    <fileset>
      <file>Geogrotesque Medium Italic.otf</file>
    </fileset>
  </family>
</familyset>
```

and try to call with in style

```
@android:style/Theme.Holo
@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView
@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText
@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView


<item name="fontFamily">Geogrotesque</item>
```

and does not work :/

Comment: Are you trying to set a custom font for the entire app or just an element?

Comment: Entire or tabtext and main title

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at few tutorials explaining how to do it in android if you really want to adjust it by modifying the styles property. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190927010741/http://blog.innovattic.com/integrating-fonts-in-android/) and its [(github project)](https://github.com/Innovattic/Android-Font-Library) is a good one explaining on how.

Here is an article in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787690/adding-custom-font-to-theme-in-android) asking the same question and it is the same in eclipse as in xamarin studio so there shoudln't be an issue there. In this post you will also find a workaround on how to modify it using code instead of the xml styles wich might be the easiest way of the two.