# How to store data in Gujarati language in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android app for Gujarat's farmers. So this app should be in Gujarati also. So is there any way so that i can store my data in Gujarati in SQLite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite [supports](http://www.sqlite.org/version3.html) both UTF-8 and UTF-16 encodings and the [Android SQLite API takes String object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which is [represented by array of UTF-16 values](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html). So you're good to go.

Comment: Thanx a lot. now if the data is in Gujarati then how to show it on my android page? I mean i have read that android phones doesn't support Gujarati language.

Comment: @AakashRayate You'll have to [embed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3424559/165674) a [Gujarati font](http://gujaratis.org/html/free-gujarati-fonts.htm) in your app.

Comment: Hi Dheeraje can you please tell me how to enter punjabi text on sqlite table column? i want to enter some punjabi text manually in database using SQLite browser.