# Android Layout Multicolor

Tags: android, android-layout, background-color

i am currently working on one Android Application and i have to set layout according to country like if application is for Korea layout color must be blue and for india layout color must be red.

So how can i achieve that?

i know about multiple language 
values-kr  // for Korea
values  //for English
values-fr // for french

but for layout i don't know.

Help Me.

Thanks in Advance[image]

Comment: You can create a Style for each values folder with the colors which you would like to use, and then use it into your layout

Comment: For Korean, it should be **values-ko_rKR** or **values-ko**, not values-kr. Or **layout-ko_rKR** or **layout-ko**, not layout-kr.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Style for each Values or in java code programming you can use a simple if statement that detects your location inside "oncreate method" and setbackground layout according to what you want using a drawable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to determine your system language. You can use

`Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();`

to get the usual language code (e.g. "de", "en").

Then, create a base Activity for your app and override **onCreate** to set the theme according to your system language. Derive all your other activities from this base Activity. Check [this tutorial](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html).

Answer (score 1):

follow type of languages

```
res/values/strings.xml
Contains English text for all the strings that the application uses,
including text for a string named title.
res/values-fr/strings.xml
Contain French text for all the strings, including title.
res/values-ja/strings.xml
Contain Japanese text for all the strings except title.
```

[How to display Korean Words in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196130/how-to-display-korean-words-in-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this piece of code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String locale = tm.getSimCountryIso();
```

and choose:

```
 if (locale.equals(pk)) 
 { 
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hazel_quick_form, container, false);
 } //fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Take example of TextView.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor" />
```

you can have `colors.xml` file in different locale folders like `values , values-fr` etc.

In example textview `@color/textcolor` can be defined with those saperated colors.xml files with different colors for different locales.

look at this.
[image]

Android will do the next magic automatically based on locale.