# How can I add 'FontAwesome' icon on Android Action Toolbar Menu?

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

Is it possible to set an Icon in ActionBar "Text" using FontAwesome?

I have tried this way...

My menu item like that..

```
   <item
     android:id="@+id/action_chat"
     android:orderInCategory="100"
     android:title="@string/action_chat"
     app:showAsAction="always"
     android:actionLayout="@layout/chat_menu_icon"/>
```

My 'chat_menu_icon.xml'

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <com.bitmakers.techmonster.textview.FontAusomeTextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:autoLink="web"
         android:id="@+id/test"
         android:gravity="center|bottom"
         android:text="@string/action_chat"
         android:textSize="24sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

My Custom Font Class

```
    package com.bitmakers.techmonster.textview;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class FontAusomeTextView extends TextView {
         public static Typeface m_typeFace = null;

         public FontAusomeTextView(Context context) {
         super(context);
         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         if (isInEditMode()) {
              return;
         }
         loadTypeFace(context);
     }

     public FontAusomeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
         if (isInEditMode()) {
              return;
          }
          loadTypeFace(context);
      }

      public FontAusomeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int   defStyle) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyle);
           if (isInEditMode()) {
           return;
           }
           loadTypeFace(context);
       }

       private void loadTypeFace(Context context) {
           if (m_typeFace == null)
                m_typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
                this.setTypeface(m_typeFace);
       }
    }
```

It is working when i using it in normal textview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I embed a custom font in an Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424165/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-android-application)

Comment: No... This post show the way in layout.... But I want to use it in my Action Menu. And also i am asking about Font Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nice library called [android-iconify](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify) to achieve your goal.

Here is how you implement it on Toolbar/Actionbar items:

`your_menu_layout.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   <item
       android:id="@+id/item_settings"
       showAsAction="ifRoom"
       android:title="@string/title"/>

</menu>
```

Inside your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.item_settings).setIcon(
new IconDrawable(this, FontAwesomeIcons.fa_cog)
    .colorRes(R.color.your_color)
    .actionBarSize());
```

And you are good to go :)

Comment: where does come from FontAwesomeIcons

Comment: `FontAwesomeIcons` is class which has constant values for all icons. When using it, it will import its static namespace.

Comment: do you have an a full example of that class, my friend? thanks

Comment: Please refer to the library link in my answer. You will find useful and comprehensive tutorial of how to implement that.

Comment: Thanks @blueware My problem is i don't know how to create FontAwesomeIcons helper class or import it... That's my sad problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom `ActionBar`

create your own layout and include that in **xml** using

```
<include.../>
```